# Upgrading suspension fork

Tags: fork, suspension, upgrades

I am currently thinking of upgrading my suspension for to something like a Rock Shox.

This is the bike I have:

https://www.cyclerepublic.com/catalog/product/view/id/4535/s/voodoo-bantu-650b-mens-mountain-bike-2016/?gclid=CjwKCAiA9f7QBRBpEiwApLGUiizwX2OekS8GOrEvZOcExb0Kroack3qj-VU7L0xlUn0AN8KaBu5L0xoCMWoQAvD_BwE

I was wondering what should I look for in term of specs so a different fork will fit my bike (i.e stem width and threadless and axle size)

Thank you for all answers

Comment: You haven't indicated what sort of riding you do, or whether the current fork is a limit.  Realistically if you're not limited by your current fork, what would a better one do for you ?

Answer (score 2):

A good place to start is looking up the specifications of your current Suntour fork: http://www.srsuntour-cycling.com/components/fork/XCM-27-5-5617.html

The important points are:

- Straight 1 1/8" diameter steerer tube
- Post type brake caliper mount for 160mm rotor
- 9mm quick-release wheel attachment

You will also need the *axle to crown* length to be the same or at least close. The Suntour page does not give it but you can measure it easily. I'm not particularly knowledgeable about MTBs but I am  guessing that most 120mm travel forks for 27.5" wheels will have about the same length.

Comment: so does this mean its not tapered

Comment: Correct, I believe it does not have a tapered steerer tube.